# ConcurrentModificationException with iterator

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

In a DTO I have

```
public class ProductTypesDto extends BaseDto {
  private List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
}
```

In my beans

```
@Entity
public class ProductTypes 
   @ManyToMany
   private Set<Colors> colors = new HashSet<>();
   ...
}
```

An user can add and remove colors for a `productTypes`

In a DTO to bean conversion, I do

```
private void convertToBeans(ProductTypesDto dto, ProductTypes beans) {
    //add element
    for (Integer color : dto.getColors()) {
        if (beans.getColors().stream().noneMatch(e -> Objects.equals(e.getId(), color))) {
            Optional<Colors> optColors = colorsRepository.findById(color);
            if (optColors.isPresent()) {
                beans.addColor(optColors.get());
            }
        }
    }
    //remove element
    for (Iterator<Colors> iterator = beans.getColors().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Colors color = iterator.next();

        if (dto.getColors().stream().noneMatch(e -> e.intValue() == color.getId())) {

            Optional<Colors> optColors = colorsRepository.findById(color.getId());
            if (optColors.isPresent()) {
                beans.removeColor(optColors.get());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

when code is running, i get

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

Seem like get this on  **iterator.next();**

Comment: Just a side note: you could also get rid of the `isPresent()`-checks followed by `get()` - `colorsRepository.findById(color).ifPresent(beans::addColor);` would be a lot more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing

`iterator.remove()`

in place of

`beans.removeColor(optColors.get());`

see the [documentation for `remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--). Note the comment

> "The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method."

Answer (score 5):

You can't iterate over `beans.getColors()` collection and remove from it by calling `beans.removeColor()` which most likely performs `colors.remove()`.

To remove the currently traversed element from the underlying collection use [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method e.g. replace:

```
beans.removeColor(optColors.get());
```

with:

```
iterator.remove();
```